# Basic practice for throwing exception/error from function

Tags: python, django

For example I have script like this

```
def form_valid:
    temp = form.save(commit=False)
    try:
       temp.contents = makecontents() 
    except:
        messages.error(self.request, error)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
    messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
    return super().form_valid(form)

def makecontents():
    if (if works well):
       return "this is my contents"
    else:
       return "this is error!!"
```

So, my basic idea is when `makecontents()` success it returns the string s and set this as member of model instance.

However `makecontents()` failed , I want to return the `error` to form_valid.

So, maybe ,, I should change `return "this is error!!"` somehow..

Is it possible? , or my idea is wrong??

Comment: What does `makecontents()` actually do, can you share the code for it? Seems like this method should be part of the form clean method if it's validating data and setting attributes on a cleaned/validated instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an`raise '<an Exception Type>("error message")'` to raise an Error, and then `except Exception as e:` to get the exception message:

```
def makecontents(works_well):
    try:
        if (works_well):
            return "this is my contents"
        else:
            raise SyntaxError("this is an error")
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
print(makecontents(works_well=False).__repr__())
```

output:

```
"this is an error"
```

Comment: Thank you ! `raise` works perfect for my purpose.